# C macro: how to hide __at keyword?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have a .h and .c file for an embedded project, which I want to unit testing in C++.
In .c file there are variable declarations:

```
uint8_t foo __at "NOINIT";
```

g++ throws error.
Has anybody a solution for this problem? (I prefer solutions which leave the .c changed)

I tried to add switch to g++:

```
-D__at=;//
```

and the expected result is:

```
uint8_t foo ;// "NOINIT";
```

But does not work. What is the correct syntax? (`-D__at=";//"` and `-D__at=;\/\/` are not)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what if you try defining it as just a semicolon?

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do.  Use a syntax like `AT("NOINIT")` instead and then just `#define AT(x)`

Comment: One big problem is that comments are removed before the preprocessor does macro expansion ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: if you use a semicolon, then you'd have `"NOINIT";` as a statement.  That is likely to elicit a compiler warning at function scope; at file scope, it should be an error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In case of function scope `#define __at ; (void)` should silence the compiler warning: `statement with no effect` (assuming that `"NOINIT";` is always after).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a trained professional. Don't try to repeat this at home.

```
 gcc \
    -D'var1(v,l)=v ## l'     \
    -D'var(v,l)=var1(v,l)'   \
    -D'__at=; const char* var(dummy_x_,__LINE__)='
```

Comment: +1: very good - I was working on something very similar but you beat me to it!

Comment: Ugg... yah, that works. Maybe it'll scare him into changing his code to use something like `AT("NOINIT")` like tmyklebu suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It works!
Unfortunately my embedded compiler supports only `__at` format, so it is not my stubborn.

Comment: @titapo you will need to define `-D"'AT(x)=__at x'` (or #define it in a header) when compiled with the embedded compiler.

Comment: @titapo: You could have a normal definition: `#define AT(x) __at x` and then your alternative might be simply `#define AT(x) /* Nothing */`.  The compiler can't object to that.